# Why is CORS Disabled by Default?

Tags: angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2

Alright, first of all, I am absolutely aware that we have a bunch of answers on this and there is a plethora of articles on the topic. I just read these answers a second before typing this:

[Why is CORS without credentials forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306080/why-is-cors-without-credentials-forbidden).
[Is CORS considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164173/is-cors-considered-bad-practice)

Etc. My particular situation is this - I just set up WebAPI2 for my practice project, the front end for which is running via gulp browser-sync. I have no idea how these ports get picked, but lets say the Web API is running on port http://localhost:1234/ and browser-sync generates the website on http://localhost:4321/. So I hit the API via angular's $http and get the famous CORS error (API controller method does get hit), so I am guessing it's the API returning not allowed. Edit: I fixed this via installing a CORS for Web API package via NuGet [(Article Here)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) before asking this Q, just referencing for anyone who might need it later.

So, I was thinking, if I deployed this, ANY request would get denied, unless I am missing something. Or would it not be denied because of something I don't understand? Is disallowing CORS just a throwback from the MVC days? Or is there some purpose to it with APIs?

Maybe I am just ranting, but this confuses the **** out of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CORS is based on the response headers returned from the API. It is not the API that rejects responding to the request, the **web browser** explicitly disallows handling the response. The API will process the request as normal.

When dealing with anything other than a GET, CORS also requires a "preflight" request to the API first, to ensure subsequent requests are allowed. This amongst sending the headers back is what the Web API nuget package provides.

CORS is off by default for security purposes.